# Calculation of days and weeks from some dates in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["11.01.2020", "05.02.2020", "01.03.2020"]})
df["data"] = df["data"].astype("datetime64")
```

And I have special dates like belo:

```
special_date = pd.to_datetime(["20.01.2020", "10.02.2020", "10.03.2020"], dayfirst=True)
```

And I need to add 4 columns to this data frame:

- col1 = number of days until the next special data
- col2 = number of weeks until the next special data
- col3 = number of days after last special data
- col4 = number of weeks afret last special data

So I need result like below: (I am not sure where I correctly calculated col2 and col4 about weekes)

[image]

Comment: your question isnt  very clear. How do you arrive at the dates shown in the `data` column based on the df and datetineindex you show?

Comment: if there is 10 days between dates, how many weeks you excpect in response?

Comment: maybe my result is not good, plese take into consideration only descriptions of col1 col2 col3 and col4 not this example result table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas date time` function in this case.
Here is a sample:

```
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d%m%Y")
```

Comment: Ok thank you but my question is how to do mentioned calculations ?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of days between two dates:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["11.01.2020", "05.02.2020", "01.03.2020"]})
df["data"]=pd.to_datetime(df["data"], dayfirst=True)

df["special_date"] = pd.to_datetime(["20.01.2020", "10.02.2020", "10.03.2020"], dayfirst=True)
df['C1'] = (df['special_date'] - df['data']).dt.days
df['C2']=((df['special_date'] - df['data']).dt.days)//7
```

This will give you:

```
        data special_date  C1  C2
0 2020-01-11   2020-01-20   9   1
1 2020-02-05   2020-02-10   5   0
2 2020-03-01   2020-03-10   9   1
```

Similarly you can find the number of weeks and days after special dates.

Comment: what is c1 c2 ? is a col1 col2 from my description ?

Comment: What I understood from your question is that you want to find the days and weeks between two dates and put them in a new column. And yes, c1 and c2 are column 1 and column 2 from your description.

Comment: perfect and are you able to also calculate col3 and col4 ? I will be really grateful

Comment: Column 3 should be 'number of days after last special data' as per your description. But, you havn't mentioned what is last special date and until what date days should be counted.

Comment: the last one date there was

Comment: last date from special dates the nearest to date from data frame

Comment: It would be great if you can add an example

Comment: Also, please consider accepting the solution if it solved the problem.